# Creating a simple button with angular2 dart and angular2_material

Tags: dart, angular

I generated an angular2 dart app with stagehand and it run as expected. Now I am trying to add a simple button from angular2-material-design to the page but not with any success. Only the button label is displayed - the button is not seen raised as expected. Below are the simple src

## .dart

```
library angular2_app.app_component;

import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';

import 'package:angular2_material/src/components/button/button.dart';

@Component( selector: 'my-app', templateUrl: 'app_component.html' )
class AppComponent {}
```

## .html

```
<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>

<md-content>
  <section layout = "row"
           layout-sm = "column"
           layout-align = "center center"
           layout-wrap>
    <md-button class = "md-raised">Button</md-button>
  </section>
</md-content>
```

Here the raised button is not seen.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `md-content`? I couldn't find it in angular2_material.

Comment: Experimenting - found it at https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector of the `MdButton` component is `[md-button].not(a)` (and some variants) which means the element needs to have an attribute `md-button` and not that the element has to be `<md-button>`. This way any element can become an `md-button` by adding this attribute.

Change the tag to

```
<div md-button>Button</div>
```

or

```
<div md-raised-button>Button</div>
```

or

```
<a md-raised-button>Button</a>
```

Also directives used in the template need to be registered with the component

```
@Component(
    selector: 'my-app')
@View(
    templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
    directives: const [MdButton])
class AppComponent {}
```

The Angular2 material components are not intended to be used at this time AFAIK and highly experimental but it's of course fine to experiment with them.

Comment: Still none of the above creates a button - just text. Just experimenting. Maybe the imports are incorrect. I tried experimenting because of the blog at http://news.dartlang.org/2015/11/how-google-uses-angular-2-with-dart.html. Just wondering why Google seems to support angular more than polymer though.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to add `directives: const [MdButton]` to your `@Component()` annotation.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Google supports Angular more than Polymer"

Comment: Thanks Gunter. The directive was the missing part. I am not trying to open a can of worms but the few times I have seen a mention of Google using angular vs dart-polymer, angular seems to be there choice. Maybe those with internal knowledge/info know better.

Comment: I guess in relation to Dart, Angular is clearly favored over Polymer. Polymer is basically for building reusable components, and building them in JS makes them more reusable than building them in Dart. Even though Polymer is great to build whole, also complex, applications, it's not its main goal. Angulars primary purpose is to make it easy to build complex applications, that's also the main goal of Dart therefore they are a prefect fit.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Most interesting view. I wonder why angular2-dart and angular2-material-design do not have a tag on stackoverflow so relevant questions can be ask. I cannot even find a timeline proposal for the dart branch of angular2.

Comment: You can just add a non-existing tag to a question and it will be created but I guess just adding two tags [tag:angular] and [tag:material-design] would be better anyway. The timeline for TypeScript, ES5/6 and Dart is the same AFAIK. They're working hard to get into beta phase - very soon it seems. I guess angular2_material is an entirely different topic though.