# How to include .less files in angular2 dart components

Tags: dart, angular, less

I want to use less preprocessor in my dart angular 2 app. What I exactly do :

1. include dependency into **pabspec.yaml** file 
   `- less_dart:
   entry_point: web/main.less
   build_mode: dart`
2. include `<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>` into index.html file
3. In web folder I added main.less file as well
   In this point my app works correct, but when I try to include other .less files in other components in leads to exaption, for instance:
4. I created file app.less, inside I writed some less code
5. In file app_component.dart I included it like: `styleUrls: const ['app.less'],`
   As result I had such exaption as:

> GET http://localhost:8080/packages/SmartPeopleUI/app.less.dart
>   An error occurred loading file: package:Project/app.less.dart

Comment: Did you add the `transformers:
  - less_dart` part in `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, yes, sure. I added dependencies: less_dart: "^0.3.3" and transformers : - less_dart:
    entry_point: web/main.less
    build_mode: dart as well

Comment: In the readme in https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/less_dart it says `entry_points'` not `entry_point`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I writed entry_points, and it gives the same effect

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I also have same issue like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193792/creating-a-simple-button-with-angular2-dart-and-angular2-material, but it doesn't help me, is there some extra samples?